# Days in a certain month

Tags: vb.net

I want to calculate how many days there are in a month. Obviously if there is a leap year then February would have 29 days.
I have some code that works out if it a leap year or not, but I do not know if it is useful.

I tried to do the current year and to count the days of the month that is entered; however there's an error and I'm not sure what to do.

```
Sub daysInMonth()
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter month you will like to calculate number of days: ")

    Dim inputMonth As DateTime = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim newMonth = DateAndTime.Month(inputMonth)
    Dim current = Now()
    Dim currentYear = (Year(current))
    Dim febuaryLeapYear = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, newMonth)
End Sub
```

Solved

Comment: You could subtract the first day from the chosen month from the first day from the month after the chosen month.

Comment: How would i do that, even if the year is a leap year?

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed that you used vba, but I believe this is .NET. In vba, without the functions, you can let the dates act as numbers. So when you subtract the first date from the last, you would receive the number of days. And in there a leap year is taken into account, since you would only use the first days of a month. So 1/3/2018 - 1/2/2018 would result in 28 and 1/3/2016 - 1/2/2016 results in 29.

Comment: What is wrong with the given code? Have you tried running it?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. 
You can find this setting in 
Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.
This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: You say:  _however there's an error_ but you don't provide any details.  I [downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I have this function which returns the number of days in any month, any year. Hope helps

```
Private Function Dates(ByVal Year As Integer, Month As Integer) As Integer
    Return DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month)
End Function
```

Comment: Lol...you simply wrapped the built-in function.  Why not just post a link to [DateTime.DaysInMonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in this case is that DaysInMonth requires the month to be expressed as an integer. So if you change inputMonth to Integer, you shouldn't receive an error.

Comment: Nothing worked, essentially the program asks the user which month to he wants to find out the number of days, so if he inputs 1 then 31 would be the output, however if it is a leap year I am unsure

Comment: What error do you get? The function you use should take leapyears into account. Otherwise, why would the function need the year as well?

Comment: Silly me, forgot to add console.writeLine with the output :). thank you able to get it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.TryParse(string, integerVariable) will check the string to see if it can be converted to an Integer. It will return True or False so it can be used in an If statemnent. In addition it fills the integerVariable with the Integer representation of the string.

The AndAlso parts of the If will never execute if the previous condition is false. This is called short circuiting. Your code will not blow up comparing numbers in the AndAlso conditions because if the first part is false it never executes.

```
Sub CalculateDaysInMonth() 'It is a bad idea to name your Sub the same as a .net method
    Do 'The method will loop until the user enters correct data
        'A more explicit message will help user to enter correct data
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a month by entering a number between 1 and 12")
        Dim inputMonth As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, inputMonth) AndAlso inputMonth > 0 AndAlso inputMonth < 13 Then
            Dim currentYear As Integer = Now.Year
            Dim numberOfDays As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, inputMonth)
            'This is an interpolated string. If your version doesn't support this you can use String.Format
            'String.Format("There are {0} in month {1} this year", numberOfDays, inputMonth)
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {numberOfDays} in month {inputMonth} this year")
            Return
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```